# AWS S3 Bucket policy Cloudfront + IAM user access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Cloudfront automatically added these bucket policy rules, but now my IAM user + production IAM role can't access the bucket to perform head object operation. How do I modify this to allow for object access for my server?

I also already tried using principle. It didn't work. The IAM user has full access to S3

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Server access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/dev"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::1234567890:distribution/asdf"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Edit: Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to see where the policy is not working.

Also, it looks like you are using an old version of the policy, so would be careful editing it directly.

Comment: > Simulation of resource-based policies isn't supported for IAM roles.

Seems like I can't test it, and yes I did test it. It said approved if I allow any principle, so policy simulator doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add access to the bucket as a policy attached to the prod role?

Comment: I gave it full S3Access policy.

Comment: Can you share the policy you have?  If the role has full access, unless there is an explicit Deny on the bucket policy, the role should have access.  Does the role allow the user to assume it?

Comment: Not sure which policy you meant, but the full bucket policy is above and the IAM policy is below. The IAM user actually has the given IAM inline policy, AdministratorAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, and CloudFrontFullAccess

Comment: The policies that are attached to the user are irrelevant because when the user assumes the production role, the user relinquishes any permissions they have.

Comment: The full bucket policy is shown in the first JSON in the question

Comment: You mentioned that the user takes on a "production IAM role".  I assume that the bottom policy is the permissions policy for that role.  What about the trust policy of the role: does it allow your principal to `sts:AssumeRole`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that in the future, I will be using a production IAM role since we only use IAM users locally. At the moment, this isn't working locally, so I haven't deployed a "role" yet.

Comment: Understood.  So the bucket policy, whatever CloudFront did to it, does not have any Deny statements, so your user's AmazonS3FullAccess should provide access to the objects in the bucket.  How is your user trying to access them and what error they get?

Comment: Using boto3's head_object method. I receive a 403 Forbidden for HeadObject operation.

Comment: Where do you run the code?